# Highcharts Change Bar Color Based on Value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts and was wondering if it was possible to have the top 3 results in a bar chart to have a different color bar then the rest of the chart?  I'm populating the chart from a CSV file.

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Spiritual Gifts Results'
            },
            colors: [
                '#3BBEE3'
            ],
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Service'
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

        var data = document.getElementById("<%= hdn_Data.ClientID %>");
        // Split the lines
        if (data.value != "") {
            var lines = data.value.split('\n');

            // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');
                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });
                }
                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else {
                    var series = {
                        data: []
                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {
                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                        }
                    });

                    options.series.push(series);

                }

            });

            // Create the chart
            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    });
```

Here is a sample CSV:

```
Categories,Administration,Evangelism,Mercy,Shepherding,Leadership,Wisdom,Teaching
Total Points,11,5,4,4,3,2,1
```

So in this example I'd like for 'Administration', 'Evangelism', and 'Mercy' to have a 'blue bar color' while the 'Shepherding', 'Leadership' etc. have a 'red bar color'.

Is this possible?

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vP2rM/6/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on OP's comment, striked my previous answer.

<strike>As you are doing,</strike>

```
series.name = item;
```

and

```
series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
```

Like wise, you can do,

```
series.color: '#f6f6f6'
```

*(in your loop you can change color based your conditions )*

You can do,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Spiritual Gifts Results'
        },
        colors: [
            '#3BBEE3'
            ],
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Service'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    var data = document.getElementById("hdn_Data");
    // Split the lines
    if (data.value != "") {
        var lines = data.value.split('\n');

        // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                });
            }
            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else {
                var series = {
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    var data = {};
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
                    } else {
                        data.y = parseFloat(item);
                        if (itemNo <= 3) {
                            data.color = 'Gray';
                        }
                        else {
                            data.color = '#3BBEE3';
                        }
                        series.data.push(data);
                    }
                });
                options.series.push(series);
              }
            });

            // Create the chart
            var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeNRM/1/)

Refer [this](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series), you can give `data` in 3 ways. I've used the third one.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to change the color-- but it seems to change the color for every item in the graph, even if I wrapped it in a conditional it seems to change the color of every bar in the bar graph.  What I want to is to change the color of the bars for the top 3 categories.

Comment: Update your code here and also show a fiddle link, so that I can check

Comment: Here's a fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vP2rM/6/ (let me know if that worked, I've never fiddled before)

Comment: @mint, I've updated my answer, do look at it. Mark as answer if it helps you :)

Comment: The best thing I learned from this is that you can programmatically manipulate your entire options object in javascript before you render the chart. That allows you to dynamically set any of the options in the entire chart to just what you want.

Comment: Here is an update of the page that gives the 3 ways to add data : [http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a Example

```
data: [
  { y: 34.4, color: 'red'},   // this point is red
  21.8,                        // default blue
  {y: 20.1, color: '#aaff99'}, // this will be greenish
  20                           // default blue
]
```

Comment: This is actually the cleanest approach, since the OP's example has data-structure-parsing concerns mixed up with formatting the data points. Probably a mixture of a custom formatter with simple logic and pre-formatting the data like this is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
In your push execution you should be able to set color for that point. I am not too familiar with push as we use a precompiled data object that we send. But inside of our .NET we set the color (if needed) on a particular point and then send the data object to the chart.

Comment: I'm using the javascript version... not sure where this functionality would be for the js one, but I'll poke around and see.  Thanks for some direction.