# How do I change a specific bar color in Highcharts Bar Chart?

Tags: highcharts

I am putting together a barchart that shows 24 bars and how much production is done in each hour of the day.

Pretty simple.

I am using `Highcharts.js` version 4.0.1

However, I want to make this extra cool and make the current hour's bar have a different color (so you can see which bar you should look at for what hour).

So lets say:

- you have 24 bars from left to right
- It is 3PM in the afternoon
- Therefore you want the "15th" bar in the series to be highlighted a certain color

Can anybody direct on this as I could not find this easily in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755236/highcharts-change-bar-color-based-on-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add a 'color' property to the series data.  For example, the following has multiple points defining different colors, and a few that use the default bar color:

```
series: [{
        data: [{y:10, color:'red'}, {y:20, color:'blue'}, {y:30, color:'#A84646'},
               {y:40, color:'rgba(253, 134, 9, 0.7)'}, 50, 60]
    }]
```